# Writing to stream is successful. But stream_get_contents() returns empty string

Tags: php

I investigate opportunity to create my own microframework using PSR7 (don't ask my why!).So I created simple httpfoundation and templating components. Now I'm testing this part of my work and have next problem. 
I create Response object:

```
public function __construct($statusCode = 200, $headers = null, $body = null)
    {
        $this->statusCode = $statusCode ? $statusCode : $this->checkedStatusCode($statusCode);
        $this->headers = $headers ? $headers : new Headers();
        $this->body = $body ? $body : new Stream(fopen('php://temp', 'w+'));
    }
```

The view is successfully generated. Then I try to write it in my Response object. 
The code for this in my templating class

```
public function render(ResponseInterface $response, $template, array $data)
    {
        $output = $this->retrieve($template, $data);
        $response->getBody()->write($output);
        return $response;
    }
```

...and in Stream class

```
public function write($string)
    {
        if (!$this->isWritable()) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Could not write to stream');
        }

        $result = fwrite($this->stream, $string);
        if ($result === false) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Could not write to stream');
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

I think the result is successful because $result contains the number of bytes written!
After that I try to retrive contents from my Response object with method dispatch() from Response class

```
public function dispatch()
    {
        return $this->getBody()->getContents();
    }
```

...and method getContents() from Stream class

```
public function getContents()
    {
        if (!$this->stream) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("Stream is not readable");
        }

        $result = stream_get_contents($this->stream);
        if ($result === false) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("Error reading of stream");
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

I get empty string!
Please help me understand where I lose written body! And why I get empty string!
Thank U!

Comment: Where do you suppose the stream pointer is after you've finished writing to it?

Comment: [right...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37OWL7AzvHo) you give the functions that executes, but don't show how the code "flows".

Comment: @Mark Baker at the end of stream. Am I wright?

Comment: @Xorifelse If you have some time you can check https://github.com/John1803/gallery/tree/templating

Comment: @JohnnyMnemonick - That's what I'd say, I'd suggest that you need to do a [rewind()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) or [fseek()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) to the beginning before you can read from it

Comment: @Mark Baker Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When writing to Stream is successful but `stream_get_contents($this->stream);` gives you an empty string then the pointer was most likely not set to the beginning of the stream. Setting the pointer to the beginning is possible in a couple of ways.

Possibility #1

```
// supply a maxlength, and offset
$contents = stream_get_contents($this->stream, -1, 0);
```

Possibility #2

```
rewind($this->stream);
$contents = stream_get_contents($this->stream);
```

Possibility #3

```
fseek($this->stream, 0);
$contents = stream_get_contents($this->stream);
```